# Populating TableView in WatchKit Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

This is how I currently populate my table view in WatchKit:

```
    - (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    // Configure interface objects here.

    menuItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Pizza", @"Chicken", @"Bread", nil];

    for (NSString *item in menuItems)
    {
        MenuRowController *menuRow = [myTableView rowControllerAtIndex:[menuItems indexOfObject:item]];
        [menuRow.menuItemLabel setText:item];
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Extension[980:19597] Error - attempt to ask for row 0. Valid range is 0..0
Printing description of item:
Pizza
2015-07-05 01:58:07.284 ScanBarWatch WatchKit Extension[980:19597]    Error - attempt to ask for row 1. Valid range is 0..0
2015-07-05 01:58:14.780 ScanBarWatch WatchKit Extension[980:19597] Error - attempt to ask for row 2. Valid range is 0..0
```

I tried looking up this error online for a couple of hours but to no avail. No one seems to have a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set the number of rows of the table:

```
[self.tableView setNumberOfRows:[menuItems count] withRowType:@"MenuRowController"];
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, error came from a copy and paste problem in IB - the Module being used was from the other project.

- [image]

Updating this fixed issue.

[image]